# With Matplotlib is it possible to annotate the latest datapoint from live data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i am currently working on a hobby project and got stuck on annotations in Matplotlib.

I have 2 Python files, one which scrapes the current price of a stock from yahoo and the current time. This information is then written in an csv:

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
import csv
import random
import time
from datetime import datetime


fieldnames = ['MSFTPrice', 'CurrentTime']

with open('MSFT.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames= fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
count = 0
while True:
    with open('MSFT.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames= fieldnames)

        MSFTPrice = si.get_live_price("MSFT")
        count += 1.0
    
        now = datetime.now()

        CurrentTime = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

        info = {
            "MSFTPrice": '%.2f' %MSFTPrice,
            "CurrentTime": CurrentTime}

        csv_writer.writerow(info)

        print('%.2f'%MSFTPrice, CurrentTime)
    
        time.sleep(1)
    
        if count >= 10000:
            break
```

So the second one is then reading those 2 values and then creates a live visualization with matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

plt.style.use('dark_background')

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('MSFT.csv')
    x = data ["CurrentTime"]
    y = data ["MSFTPrice"]

    plt.cla()

    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Price')

    plt.plot(x, y, color= 'green', linewidth=1.5)
    plt.xticks(x[::300],fontsize= 12,  rotation='horizontal')

    for i,j in zip(x,y):
        plt.annotate (str(j), xy = (i,j))


    plt.tight_layout()

    plt.grid(b=None)

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I want to annotate only the latest datapoint from the csv, but currently it annotate all datapoints. Here is a screenshot on how it looks now:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPFqc.png)

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: The x,y that I got from the csv and substituted is in pandas series format, so I think @perl's answer will work if you do `x = data ["CurrentTime"].tolist();y = data ["MSFTPrice"].tolist()`.

Comment: Yes now it seems to work as intended, thank you and @pearl so much :).

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the following (which annotates all points in a loop):

```
for i,j in zip(x,y):
    plt.annotate (str(j), xy = (i,j))
```

with the statement annotating the latest point (`x[-1], y[-1]`):

```
plt.annotate(str(y[-1]), xy=(x[-1], y[-1]))
```